# In APL, how can I compute the lowest unused positive integer from a given set of integers?

Tags: tacit-programming, apl

For example, given 1 8 4 9 0 2 , return 3. Thanks.

Comment: If this is homework, can you post what work you've done so far to try and solve the problem?

Comment: It's not homework, though I do work from home. But I can take the max of the list, generate the indices up to that maximum number,   remove the items from the list then take the min of the remaining items, but this is not going to be a good solution.

Comment: Not an answer, because it's the wrong language, but in k4 it's the rather beautiful `{*&~(x@<:x)=!#x}`

Comment: Or even the slightly shorter `{*&~(!#x)in x}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  {⍬⍴(⍳1+⍴⍵)~⍵} 1 8 4 9 0 2
```

3

Comment: Thanks, but I can't read the presumabley APL font. Can you post it in psuedo code?

Comment: first(iota 1 plus shape arg)without arg

Comment: Thanks! That's genious. No matter what the magnitude of the given integers are, the answer must be less than 1 plus the count. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try

((⍳⍴n)∊n)⍳0

or

((iota rho n) element n) iota 0

This is more or less the standard idiom for choosing the next available file tie number.

Answer (score 0):

The case where they are all used seems to have "one plus the largest" as the answer, but whether that is "from" the list is another question.

@Paul, are you using APL385 as your browser's font?  That seems to have cleared up many things from this end.